# In math, how do you refer to a subscript or superscript indiscriminately?

Tags: mathematics

In a math or physics context, I would like to say the following:

> In this equation, we subscript or superscript the variables by "eq" which stands for "equilibrium".

The "eq" is added as a lowerscript to some variables (for example x<sub>eq</sub>) and as a superscript to others (y<sup>eq</sup>). Is there a way to designate both at the same time?

Alternatively, would the following be correct?

> In this equation, we decorate the variables by "eq" which stands for "equilibrium".

Comment: Just say *subscript or superscript*. There's no single word that everyone will understand for what you want.

Comment: You should probably be consistent and pick just one. Different symbolisms in math usually imply different functionality. Also, you'd probably get better answers on a math site.

Comment: You *label*. You most certainly don't *decorate*, that's the opposite of math. As a side note, you're also looking for a hypernym, not for "indifferently". To refer to these things indifferently, just use any random word at all.

Comment: Perhaps he meant indiscriminately

Comment: If the sub- or superscripts are indexes (indices for those who prefer), then you can just refer to an individual s-ors- as an "index" or "index marker" if you want to be precise. In some areas of math, like tensor analysis, there are notations that switch from sub- to super- or vice versa, depending on boundary conditions. Since you're asking for a verb, _index_ works there, too. However, I'd say _with_ instead of _by_; that indicates the "eq" is a marker, not a property measuring some trait.

Comment: My current professor refers to sub/superscript text simply as "scripted text".  I don't know how official it is, but I know what she means when she says it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a word for the common concept. The Wikipedia article is titled [Subscript and superscript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subscript_and_superscript). Throughout the article, it never uses a single word to refer to them collectively. When it wants to abbreviate, it sometimes says *sub- and/or superscript*.

Comment: OK. If there is no word for that, I think that @RegDwigнt's suggestion "we label the variables" is the best alternative.

Comment: If someone said that, I'm not sure I'd realize they means a superscript or subscript until after they show an example. But I'm not a mathematician, maybe they'd guess it right.